# Wordpress: Get Featured Image URL from Database

Tags: wordpress

How I can get URL of Featured Image from database? I will show Featured Image in front end as .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The featured image is stored in the

> wp_postmeta table with the meta_key _thumbnail_id

you can get it by

```
$Featured_image = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT p.*
  FROM net_5_postmeta AS pm
 INNER JOIN net_5_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
 WHERE pm.post_id = $da_id
   AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
 ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
 LIMIT 15
 ",'ARRAY_A'
```

or

```
SELECT * from {$wpdb->prefix}_posts 
WHERE ID in (
SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
AND post_id = ':ID'
);
```

Replace ID by your post id

To Get the Post Thumbnail URL in WordPress

```
<?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
echo $thumb_url[0];
?>
```

for reference :[URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57669/retrieve-featured-image)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
           if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
               // use the $feat_image_url variable as you like
           }
           endwhile;
         endif;
```

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    <a class="feature_image" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID())); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Note that get_post_thumbnail_id() requires the $post_id. Hope this will help you.